# Semantic HTML and BEM CSS

Tags: html, semantic-markup, bem

I'm trying to write a semantic HTML and also trying to use class names based on BEM methodology.

Before I start the project with completely wrong structure, I just wanted to double check with you if this is right, what I'm doing:

```
    <main>
      <article class="card card--light">
        <section class="card__wrapper">
          <div class="card__image">
            an image
          </div>
          <div class="card__name">
            a name
          </div>
          <div class="card__button">
            <button>Click Me</button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </article>
    </main>
```

Is it ok that all sections go inside an article?
Am I doing maybe too many divs?

Comment: Your structure is just fine.

But you may get rid of extra divs with the help of mixes (https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes):
`<button class="button card__button">Click Me</button>`
Here there's a `button` block and an element `button` of `card` block on the same DOM node.

Answer (score 3):

It's often a good choice to use an `<article>` tag for card.

There is one error, the HTML5 tag `<article>` is already creating a section of the page. So there is no meaning of having a `<section>` as only child. This `<section>` means *"I'm a section of the article"*, but that's not really the case here. So you should use a simple `<div>` instead of a `<section>`.

Globally, be careful with too much HTML5 semantic elements. Using an extra `<div>` has no bad consequences, this is not true for "sectioning content" tags  (`<article>`, `<section>`, `<nav>` and `<aside>`). For example screen reader will notifiy the visitor for each new section.

Comment: Approved. Also, you can make a good use of header / footer tags in an article, for example.

Comment: Yes! Once you are in a new section, `<header>` and `<footer>` describe the header and the footer of your section, here your `<article>`